# Display no content if the condition is not met AMP script

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dynamic, if

I'm trying to build a dynamic email with different blocks displaying based on the if/else check. I can't understand how do I display nothing and go to the next step if the condition is not met.
Here is the code:

```
var @condition
Set @condition= AttributeValue("Value")
set @content = ContentBlockById("123456")
  
IF IndexOf(@condition, "value1")>0 OR IndexOf(@condition, "value2")>0 THEN
set @block1 = @content

ELSE 
set @block1 = **here I need to display nothing**

ENDIF

]%%
%%=v(@block1)=%%
```

Is there any specific string for it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply remove the else statement like this:

```
%%[

var @condition, @block1 
Set @condition= AttributeValue("Value")
set @content = ContentBlockById("123456")
  
IF IndexOf(@condition, "value1")>0 OR IndexOf(@condition, "value2")>0 THEN
   set @block1 = @content
ENDIF

]%%
%%=v(@block1)=%%
```

If no value is populated to `@block1` variable, it will be empty.

Comment: It worked and was easier than I thought :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you find it helpful, kindly mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks